# Magento Implementing token based authentication

Tags: rest, magento, http-token-authentication

I saw some documentation here to create token based authentication.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html 
But i cant make it work. The urls in this example are not working. 
I am new to magento. Please help in integrating token authentication, because i have to integrate it with mobile app.

Comment: Could you please paste any error logs? The more information you'll provide the easier it would be to find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: It is a 404 error. Please can you tell me how to configure the same from start? The url is <host>/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Answer (score 0):

Which Magento version are you using? I ran into the same problem until I found out that the token based authentication is available for Magento 2 which is still in Beta while I'm posting this. I'm currently using Magento 1.9.1.1 hence the 404 ;)

Comment: I found out that, this is not possible to on the magento 1.7 i am using and hence i started working with soap api. Soap api is very slow but still i am forced to use it because i cant figure out any other way.

Comment: Although it is still a prototype, what we did was to use a [wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/magentojs) that calls the Magento SOAP API. The advantage of such an approach is that it lets your mobile client call your server with REST methods and let your server that uses the wrapper as a bridge to propagate the call to the Magento API. Moreover, it avoids each client to open a SOAP connection. This becomes your server job which makes requests faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to use token based authentication on the Magento 1.x version. You need to write this functionality to you for your own. You can also follow this article for more details.

https://www.ipragmatech.com/magento-token-base-rest-api-for-authentication-and-authorization